# HTML Won't Properly align to Center a Div/Image

Tags: html, css

Okay, I've been into HTML for a while now, and I have never had this issue before, what my problem is basically is I try to make a Valentine's Day page, and it won't allow me to center a image to use it as background for the page.
CSS Below:

```
body {
font-family: modern;
background-color: #ffcccc;
}

.container {
width: 1200px;
}

.bgimg {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

@font-face {
font-family: modern;
src: url("modern.ttf")
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bgimg">
        <img src="valentinebg.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this issue is really strange, I did it all:
`margin-right` and `margin-left` won't work and I got no idea why.

Comment: You need to give the div with the class `.bgimg` a width.. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dr2tB/)**

Comment: If it's supposed to be a background image....why are you not using the background-image property? At the moment you have an inline (as in, IN THE HTML) image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align:center;` to .bgimg and remove margin left and right.

If you want to center the container also you should apply

```
.container {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/uVa2Q/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are supposed to be using a background image then you should be using the bg image property.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYgS3/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background-image: Url(http://bocamag.com/site_media/uploads/February%202014/vday.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
```